# Software for displaying animated gifs?

Tags: linux

I've been searching for days but have yet to find an application that can play scaled up animated gifs without getting choppy. The basic requirements are:

- Scaled to full screen (1080x1920)
- No window showing
- Hidden mouse cursor
- Smooth rendering

Any favorite stripped-down image viewers out there?

Comment: Do you really have a 1080p animated gif?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is soliciting a software recommendation, which tend to become obsolete and often aren't broadly applicable. 

Answer (score 5):

Some of the tools in the **ImageMagick** suite (`apt-get install imagemagick`) will help. The [animate](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/animate.php) command will display animated .gifs:

```
animate myimg.gif
```

The window is by default borderless (you do have to be in an X GUI).  You can resize:

```
animate -resize 1920x1080 myimg.gif
```

Notice that's width by height (see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry) for the various ways to specify geometry).  However, it won't warp a square gif into a rectangular one (maybe there is a way to force that, there are a lot of options).  Also, resizing will probably make a mess of most animated gifs.  You need to process them first:

```
convert myimg.gif -coalesce myimg2.gif
```

The converted `myimg2.gif` should work properly with `animate -resize`.

Comment: Just noting that ImageMagick requires X11 (I'm trying to display animated GIFs on Raspbian without X11)

Comment: @PaulSlocum It's unusual to bother with graphics on GNU/Linux sans X, but it isn't impossible; investigate [the framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer).  Apps have to be written specifically for it and there are at least one or two for displaying images ([FIM](http://www.nongnu.org/fbi-improved/) and what it was derived from, `fbi`), but I dunno if they do animated gifs ([looks like no for FIM](http://www.nongnu.org/fbi-improved/FIM.html), but there is the suggestion there the code base could be useful in doing so).

Comment: Unfortunately fbi and SDL_Image only can display the first frame.  I'm planning to try using SDL with some other image library like freeimage.  Also looking into piping ffmpeg libraries to convert animated GIFs into an mpeg4 stream that omxplayer can handle.

Comment: For me it isn't a borderless window??

Answer (score 1):

If you take the time to understand the animated gif format, this is not possible. You can't realistically have an animated gif which is at a lower resoltion and "scale it" to 1080p and not expect it to be "choppy". You need to understand how frame transitions work. This isn't vector data.

You seem to be confusing what a gif file is with a proper video format.
Either acquire the content in a sensible format, or do your best to convert it to one using [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org) then playback with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

Also, this is not a Raspberry Pi specific question.